# Why Xcode 9 always asks me for Provisioning Profile Again when archiving?

Tags: code-signing, app-distribution

I have selected provisioning profile in for my Target, but Xcode again asks for provisioning profile when I export the app.

What is the reason behind it? As it was not observed in previous versions of Xcode.

Another subquestion is - What would happen if I select another provisioning profile from the menu?

Here is the screenshot of it -
This screen comes up when archiving.

[image]

Comment: did you ever resolve this?